# How to register Quartz.Net jobs dynamically in .Net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, quartz.net, quartz

I am using Quartz.Net 3.2.0 with a .net core application and here is my requirement.

Users can alter the schedule from UI, they can select the report they want to send at any specific time or schedule. Now, I have all this info in the backend table, which I am getting through an API.

I know with quartz we can schedule jobs using cron expression at a specific time, but my requirement is, that my jobs are not fixed, these can vary each day. So I need to dynamically refresh the scheduled jobs daily, maybe I can do it at night at one time, and then all jobs will perform at the given time I am getting through API.

But I don't know how to dynamically register the jobs and refresh them daily basis, I am new to quartz.Net.

Please suggest me approach and sample code to do this, thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest scheduling a job to schedule your jobs...

Comment: but scheduling the jobs will happen in Startup file where we have configureServices method, how I can call this configureService manually?

Comment: One option would be to user one schedule that runs every minute and use a database to store the specific tasks and their interval and execute it when the correct minute is hit.

Comment: hitting the database every minute might be a bad idea, it might cause the database lock to keep too busy the table

Comment: If a database hit every minute causes issues you need a new server...